# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetTop')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to create a scroll effect. When you click on the options on the navbar, we go to a specific section.

Why am I getting this error?

This is the code where the error is coming:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
export default function Home() {
    const about = useRef(null);
    const work = useRef(null);
    const contact = useRef(null);

    const scrollSection = (elementRef) => {
        window.scrollTo({
          top: elementRef.current.offsetTop,
          behavior: "smooth",
        });
      };
    return (
        <>
            <div ref={about} className='first'>
                <nav className="navbar">

                    <div className="logo">
                        <video loop autoPlay muted playsInline className='logo_video' >
                            <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <div className="about_section">
                        <ul className="list">
                            <li className="info about">
                                <div className="infoindex" onClick={() => scrollSection(about)}>
                                    About
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="info">
                                <div className="infoindex" onClick={scrollSection(work)}>
                                    Work

                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li className="info">
                                <div className="infoindex" onClick={scrollSection(contact)}>
                                    Contact

                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </nav>
```

What are some edits I can do to this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the following lines of code:

```html
<div className="infoindex" onClick={() => scrollSection(about)}>
<div className="infoindex" onClick={scrollSection(work)}>
<div className="infoindex" onClick={scrollSection(contact)}>
```

Now you can see the difference. *scrollSection(work)* and *scrollSection(contact)* are triggering the scrollSection function in each render even if you don't click them. Don't forget to add the arrow function to them.

```html
<div className="infoindex" onClick={() => scrollSection(about)}>
<div className="infoindex" onClick={() => scrollSection(work)}>
<div className="infoindex" onClick={() => scrollSection(contact)}>
```

By the way, you are only handling the about reference at the div parent:

```html
<div ref={about} className='first'>
```

You need to handle the rest of references too and don't forget the onClick event. If your *about* div wraps the rest of the *divs*, then it could have unwanted behaviors if you want to click the child *divs* inside the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not passing `work` and `contact` refs to elements as you are doing with the `about` ref. They are never being set, and this is why you are getting null current.
2. You should not call the `scrollSection` directly in the `onClick`, but rather pass a callback function that executes when the `div` is clicked:

   ```html
   <div className="infoindex" onClick={() => scrollSection(work)>Work</div>
   ```

   and

   ```html
   <div className="infoindex" onClick={() => scrollSection(contact)}>Contact</div>
   ```